# Show connection string in one environment, but hide it in another environment

Tags: c#, config, connection-string, directive

I am working on a C# project which works in two differents environments.

I need to have the connection string in one environment and hide/comment it another environment by #if #else #endif.

As I see, I can not do that.

Now my question is how can I reach my idea in only one config file.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Visual Studio as your ide, I would recommend using this tool called `Configuration Transform` which can helo you handle different environment configurations.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GolanAvraham.ConfigurationTransform

Comment: Can you accept the answer if that fit for you?

Comment: Thanks. I'll use that.

Comment: Sure. Would appreciate vote up and answer acceptence